# return value only when it is available else wait for the value..... c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, get, set

Return the value only when it is available. if I use a condition to check the null condition it is throwing a exception. "saying not all code paths return a value"

```
 internal PinMessage()
        {
            obj.PinsAvailable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(HandlePinsAvailable);
        }
    private void HandlePinsAvailable(byte[] pinBytes)
    {
        pinmesssage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pinBytes);
    }

    internal string GetPinMessage(string AccoutNumber)
    {
        string pinstring = string.Empty;
        obj.SendPinRequest(AccoutNumber);
        pinstring = pinmesssage;
        return pinstring;
    }

    private string _pinMessage;
    public string pinmesssage
    {
        get//Not all Code paths return a value
        {
            if (_pinMessage != null)
            return _pinMessage;
        }
        set { _pinMessage = value; }
    }
```

Comment: I want to recheck it. Because I get the response from a device and I want to check until I get the response with out blocking any threads that are running

Comment: add an `else` after your if statement and do something.  The program doesn't know what to do if _pinMessafe is null

Comment: I want to wait until the property is SET and then return the value

Comment: What would you be waiting for?

Comment: I get the response from the Device which I collect in HandlePinsAvailable Method. When I enter the value in the device. the value is collected. The application is not waiting until the event is triggered and the delegated. I used AutoReset class but it is blocking all the other threads in the application

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this compile error because you don't return anything in the case where _pinMesSafe is null.  You need to return something from your Access or in the case when that is true, or throw an exception.

Comment: Can I hold the method until I _pinmessafe is SET

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to make Get{} inaccessible until Set{} is called within the scope of that property.  If it is, then I'd say that you need a different approach because that's not how Get and Set are intended to be used (generally).

Comment: Is there any way that I can make this GetPinMessage method wait under I get the message from HadlePinsAvailable.....?

Comment: Yes, you can easily enforce that somewhere else in the code - ensure that Get is never called before Set.  It still won't fix your compile error, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private string _pinMessafe;
     public string pinmesssage
     {
         get {
             if (_pinMessafe != null)
                 return _pinMessafe;
                                }
         set { _pinMessafe = value; }
     }
```

You have to return something when it's being called, you can't just put a method call on hold.
What you could do is force a check yourself:

```
   private string _pinMessafe;
     public string pinmesssage
     {
         get {
             return _pinMessafe ?? GetMessage()
         }
         set { _pinMessafe = value; }
     }
```

In this scenario, `GetMessage()` would have to take care of returning the message. It's hard to give a more detailed answer with the information you've provided. 
You should edit your code to make it more readable (this includes the english spelling errors) and add info if needed.

Comment: this get set property is just a try. Actually Until I get a value in "HandlePinsAvailable" method I should not return the value in "GetPinMessage". I should wait for the pinbytes in "pinmesssage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pinBytes);"

Comment: Sounds like you have to revise your design in general. Why can't you create a method that checks whether the end of the information stream has been reached and use that to determine whether or not the values can be collected?

Comment: Ya i think i have to revise my design because i am sending and trying to listen the response from the same method where both of them are two different threads.......... when ever i get the data bytes in the HandlePinsAvailable I have to push it to the main thread

Answer (score 0):

This is not the "best" practice, but will work and let your consumer wait until the producer has written the variable.

```
private string _pinMessafe;
object locker = new object();

public string pinmesssage
{
    get
    {
        string x = null;
        while(x == null) {
          lock(locker) { x = _pinMessafe ; }
          Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        return x;
    }
    set { lock(locker) { _pinMessafe = value; } }
}
```

Comment: this is creating a infinite loop and never coming out... and blocking all the threads...

Comment: That's what you wanted wasn't it? You wanted to "recheck" the value until it was valid. If that is not what you wanted, then I misunderstood the question.